# How do i print the dictionary using default keys

Tags: python, dictionary

if `list=[1,2,3]` and `list1=['a','b','c','d','e']`, how would you print a dictionary containing values from list as keys
and values from list1 as value.

If there are no keys for a value in `list1`,
it would assign a default key for the same dictionary.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
keys=[1,2,3]
list1=['a','b','c','d','e']

dct = dict(zip(keys, list1[:len(keys)]))

if len(list1) > len(keys):
    dct['default'] = list1[len(keys):]
print(dct)
```

Out:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 'default': ['d', 'e']}
```